# jasmine-jquery/fixture - where to include/require brunch devDependencies?

Tags: brunch, jasmine-jquery, karma-jasmine

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: affix`

I'm trying to run a Jasmine spec and it cannot find `affix` from `jasmine-fixture`.  My spec isn't using a `require`, but I haven't seen any references that it is needed.

What is more troublesome is that there isn't any reference to `affix` or `jasmine` for that matter in my `vendor.js` because it is a devDependency only, so I'm not sure how it would be available to the karma runner/jasmine spec.

bower.json:

```
{
    "name": "af-calendar",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "main": "public/js/app.js",
    "ignore": [
        "**/.*",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "moment": ">=2.5.1",
        "moment-range": "alienfast/moment-range#3454882ae8e0493b20ff1c6651956b906c8f975d",
        "jquery": ">=1.10.2",
        "jquery-ui": ">=1.10.3",
        "jquery-simulate": "*"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "jasmine-jquery": ">=2.0.3",
        "jasmine-fixture": ">=1.2.0"
    },
    "overrides": {
        "jquery-simulate": {
            "main": "jquery.simulate.js",
            "dependencies": {
                "jquery": "*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

brunch-config.coffee

```
exports.config =
    files:
        javascripts:
            joinTo:
                'js/vendor.js': /^(bower_components|vendor)/
                'js/app.js': /^app/

#            pluginHelpers: 'js/app.js'

        stylesheets:
            joinTo:
                'css/vendor.css': /^(vendor|bower_components)/
                'css/app.css': /^app/

#       templates:
#            joinTo: 'js/app.js'

    plugins:
        autoReload:
            enabled:
                js: on
                css: on
                assets: off

        imageoptimizer:
            path: 'images'
            smushit: no

        coffeelint:
            pattern: /^app\/.*\.coffee$/

            options:
#                indentation:
#                    value: 4
#                    level: "warn"
#
                max_line_length:
                    level: "ignore"

    conventions:
        assets: /(assets|vendor\/assets|font)/
```

### Question

I don't want to ship them or have them included in the vendor.js.  How do I include/require them for just for my karma/jasmine spec testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that test-only dependencies are loaded via the `files` section of the karma.conf.  While for most code we are used to just including a new dependency in the bower.json (which ends up in the app.js or vendor.js depending on the brunch config), `devDependencies` are not included in any combined file and must be referenced specifically such as:

```
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'public/js/**/*.js',
        'bower_components/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',
        'bower_components/jasmine-fixture/dist/jasmine-fixture.js',
        'spec/spec_helper.coffee',
        'spec/**/*.spec.coffee'
    ],
```

This is not as convenient as how brunch combines files for vendor.js, and could be better, but the above works for now.